# Different representations of the perspective projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

So in the textbook, we want to map $(x,y,z,1)$ to $\big(\frac{x}{1-\frac{z}{d}}, \frac{y}{1-\frac{z}{d}}, 0, 1\big)$. Since we are working with homogenous coordinates, this is the same thing as mapping $(x,y,z,1)$ to $(x,y,0,1-\frac{z}{d})$. It can be shown the perspective matrix to map this is:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
    1& 0& 0 & 0 \\
    0& 1& 0 & 0 \\
    0& 0& 0 & 0 \\
    0& 0& -1/d & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, what I was wondering was if I could just map it from $(x,y,z,1)$ to $\big(\frac{x}{1-\frac{z}{d}}, \frac{y}{1-\frac{z}{d}}, 0, 1\big)$ which gives:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{d}}& 0& 0 & 0 \\
    0& \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{d}}& 0 & 0 \\
    0& 0& 1 & 0 \\
    0& 0&  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The final homogeneous vector by applying $P$ to $(x,y,z,1)$ is the same but clearly the matrices $P$ are different. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with doing what I did and have a matrix in terms of the input $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of your transformation cannot depend on the point, it has to be a constant matrix. There is a one to one correspondence between matrices and transformations (for any given basis).